# How to use ".yaml" to load modules on cluster using "envmodules" and "--use-envmodules" in snakemake

Tags: python, cluster-computing, pipeline, slurm, snakemake

I have a `snakefile` like this (only for dep:

```
rule test:
    input:
        text='catthis.txt'
    output:
        "test.txt"
    envmodules: 
        "modules.yaml"
    shell:
        "cat {input.text} > ./{output}"
```

My `modules.yaml` file contains this:

```
modules:
    "StdEnv/2020",
    "gcc/9.3.0"
```

So in the end, I'd like to have something like this, when snakemake is called:

```
rule test:
    input:
        text='catthis.txt'
    output:
        "test.txt"
    envmodules: 
        "StdEnv/2020",
        "gcc/9.3.0"
    shell:
        "cat {input.text} > ./{output}"
```

Perhaps this is not possible, but I found nowhere on the [snakemake website here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v5.12.3/snakefiles/deployment.html) that would allow this. But I'd be much more practical for me to have one file to call rather than pasting the modules to be loaded in all the rules (here I'm showing one, but imagine I have 50 rules...)

When running the snakemake (assuming everything is in the same directory)

```
snakemake -p --cores 1 --use-envmodules
```

it doesn't work (using the `modules.yaml`), but it does work if the modules are put directly in the `snakefile`.

The `catthis.txt` contains only this text `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`, again for demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this is to place the envmodules in the config file:

```
# config.yaml
envmodules:
  stdenv: "StdEnv/2020"
  gcc: "gcc/9.3.0"
```

Then you can call

```
configfile: 'config.yaml'
envmodules = config['envmodules']
rule test:
    input:
        text='catthis.txt'
    output:
        "test.txt"
    envmodules: 
        envmodules['stdenv'],
        envmodules['gcc']
    shell:
        "cat {input.text} > ./{output}"
```

That will make it clearer at the rule which envmodules are expected while allowing you to keep track of versions in one place.  I use something similar for containers.

If you really want to keep the yaml separate, you can load multiple config files, though that's more challenging to ensure keys are not overwritten.